# incrementing numbers in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, increment

I am creating a job number system that a few users will be using at the same time. I have created a job number on the php page and then it saves the number to the job sheet and uses this to link other tables to the job.
I take the job number from a table called numbers which then should increment the number by 1 each time the job is submitted ready to create the next job. 
But the numbers are not working correctly.
As an example I get 1,2,3,4,8, then 43,44,45,then 105
I cant see why they would jump so much

```
$job_number_query = "SELECT * FROM numbers";
            $job_result =($mysqli-> query($job_number_query)) ;
            $job_num = mysqli_fetch_assoc($job_result);
            $increment_job_number = $job_num[job_number];
            $update_job_number_query = "UPDATE numbers SET job_number = $increment_job_number +1 ";     
            $mysqli-> query($update_job_number_query);
            //echo ($customer_id);
```

Then I simply insert the $increment_job_number into the jobsheet table.

I am using int for the Job_number field in the table numbers
I cant think of a way to test the numbers. I guess a way is to look through the jobsheets and add another number to there but because more than one user might have a job that hasn't been submitted yet would this also cause problems.

Comment: Why not just use an auto incrementing field as the job number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was me that was the technical failure in the end. I have got the incremental numbers on the create page but then unfortunately I had also got the incremental number on the edit pages so every time I edited the pages I then added 1 to the number field in the numbers table.

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the value without the first SELECT:

```
UPDATE numbers SET job_number = job_number +1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `where` clause on your `update` query, so you're incrementing the job_number field in **ALL** records in the table.